# JComboBox and vetoableChange?

Tags: java, swing, combobox

When a user changes the value in a JComboBox, I want to prompt them to confirm the change.  If they say "no," the old value will remain.  If they say "yes," the new value will be selected.

I tried adding a VetoableChangeListener to the combobox, but this does not ever seem to be fired!

Per the JavaDoc for JComponent.addVetoableListener, "Adds a VetoableChangeListener to the listener list. The listener is registered for all properties."

Any idea of what is going on?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a subclass of JComboBox and overload setSelectedItem.  BEFORE setting the new value, call fireVetoableChange.  If the exception is thrown, do not set the new value.  If no exception is thrown, call super.setSelectedItem.

Comment: If you have to override `setSelectedItem` anyway, you might as well do the "Do you want to change this item?" code right in `setSelectedItem` and not bother calling `fireVetoableChange` and using a `VetoableChangeListener`.